# CreateRemoteThread: Memory Management

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, createremotethread

I'm wondering about the `LPVOID lpParameter` parameter of the [CreateRemoteThread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682437%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function. Because processes don't share memory, the remote thread can't access a struct in our process. So, does the function copy the parameter and manages it by it own or do we need to allocate memory with [VirtualAllocEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366890%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and then call [WriteProcessMemory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681674%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to actually copy the struct into the remote process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CreateRemoteThread` does not do any automatic management of `lpParameter`. You are correct, it is up to the developer to ensure that `lpParameter` is a valid pointer in the context of the target process. `VirtualAllocEx` and `WriteProcessMemory` are definitely options for doing so.

Comment: Note also that the parameter doesn't actually have to be a pointer.  If you only need to pass a single parameter (and it will fit) you can cast it to LPVOID and back again.  An example might be passing a handle you've copied into the target process using DuplicateHandle.